# Use of Spring data JPA with maven in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm new with Spring and I would like to use Spring Data with Jpa, Maven and Mysql in Eclipse environment. Then I'm going to use Tomcat as application server
I read a lot of tutorial but all of them are different from each other therefore don't understand what I have really to do. At the moment I'm confusing between these technology and DAO/DAL structure
Must I use Hibernate?
I have to use it with java JPA and then I have to add Spring data?
If anyone has an example or a tutorial I thank him.

Comment: Did you check http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/

Comment: do you refer to this guide? http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.0.RELEASE/reference/html/
the problem it's that this guide is only for Spring data and not for all

Comment: Oh i thought maven,mysql,eclipe you know already. But googling got http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-jpa-data-hibernate-mysql/

Comment: Hibernate is optional, it depends on your use case what you want to do. Its a ORM for mapping your db tables into java objects. But if you are just testing queries to load data you can use spring jpa queries directly, you will find examples in spring-data-jpa link

Answer (score 0):

Official [spring data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa) link

For spring-data-jpa,maven,mysql,hibernate,eclipse example [tutorial](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-jpa-data-hibernate-mysql)

Hibernate is optional, it depends on your use case what you want to do. Its a ORM for mapping your db tables into java objects and have lot of other features like session caching, second level caching, criteria queries, validation, search/filters etc.

If you are just testing queries to load data you can use spring jpa queries directly, you will find examples in spring-data-jpa link

Comment: I downloaded the whole project but  I would like to start from zero with a new project to undestand how i do